# How to create the following data structure in an SQL environment

Tags: sql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-structures, nosql

I have a FireStore database and I need to convert it to SQL. My `SeminarsAndTraining` document looks like this:

```
{
  "st_name": "SOL Level 1",
  "attendance": [
    {"date": "01/29/2021", "present": ["9103", "1282"], "absent": ["8127"]},
    {"date": "01/29/2021", "present": ["1203", "1224"], "absent": ["0927"]}
  ] 
}
```

I have multiple of these `SeminarsAndTraining` documents inside a collection. The object inside the `attendance` array contains the date for the attendance and the students' id is stored in the `present` and `absent` array.

**Problem 1**
I know you can't have arrays in SQL, so what is the best approach to this?.

```
"attendance": [
    {"date": "01/29/2021", "present": ["9103", "1282"], "absent": ["8127"]},
    {"date": "01/29/2021", "present": ["1203", "1224"], "absent": ["0927"]}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database you'll typically have these tables

- `SeminarsAndTraining`, which stores `st_name`
- `SeminarsAndTraining_attendance`, which stores the `date` of each attendance, and the ID of the `SeminarsAndTraining` it belong to.
- `SeminarsAndTraining_attendance_present`, which stores each ID from the `present` field, and the ID of the `SeminarsAndTraining_attendance` it belong too.
- `SeminarsAndTraining_attendance_absent`, which stores each ID from the `abssent` field, and the ID of the `SeminarsAndTraining_attendance` it belong too.

You could probably merge the last two tables, and include a `present_or_absent` value for each.